Speech Recognition failed to recognize double zero with one
When i speak two double zero one or three double zero one it is returning me three zeros everytime before numbers and it only happens when the last number is one and there are number before "double".
<script>

    const startButton = document.getElementById('startButton')
    const stopButton = document.getElementById('stopButton')

        const recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
    
        recognition.continuous = false;
        recognition.lang = "en-US";
        recognition.interimResults = false;
        recognition.maxAlternatives = 1;
    
        recognition.onresult = (event) => {
        const numericdatas = event.results[0][0].transcript;
            console.log('numericdatas',numericdatas)
        };
    
    startButton.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        recognition.start();
    })
    stopButton.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        recognition.stop();
    })
</script>

